# Is there a way to have HTML code from another file run 'natively' within a main HTML file?

Tags: html

I have already tried ,  and other embedding methods, however what I want to achieve is for the HTML code from another HTML file to run as if it was 'natively' in the main HTML file.

For example, within my index.html file I'd like for it to access another text file that has simple HTML code within it. Not via embedding but by running as if the code was inside where it's referenced with CSS formatting relative to the index.html  file.

Comment: Use Javascript - One option out of so many is using [jquery load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: You can use jQuery.parseHTML() to convert your text html to html

Comment: Using pure HTML your options are ugly and not considered best practice. `Frames` (now obsolete) and `iFrames` have been used for this, but should really be avoided. I've seen hacks using the `object` tag too but it is not a reliable approach.

Answer (score 0):

Use some HTML preprocessor (like PHP):

```
<div id="footer">
    <?= file_get_content('footer.html'); ?>
</div>
```

That way there will be real *native* include - no delay for fetching content via internet when main HTML is already loaded. JS/CSS does not even see it as included content.